# Powershell won't load fully on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell

Recently, I noticed a number of applications/wouldn't load anymore. Upon further investigation, I found that they all relied on a script execution or on powershell. When I try to launch powershell, it won't load fully and I don't get a command prompt (this is regardless of whether I use the 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit version of Powershell):

[image]

The conhost process does indeed exist as a child process of the powershell:

[image]

but I get no command prompt. I am guessing this is the reason why some of my applications/shortcuts won't load anymore. The normal command prompt (`cmd`) runs fine.

I have tried the following, to no avail (i.e. no issue reported):

- `sfc /scannow`
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth`
- `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth`

What else could I try? This is nmy Windows version:

[image]

The powershell is version is 5.1.17763.1.

**Update #1**

Starting Powershell creates 2 events in Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Powershell\Operational, I have obfuscated the computer name:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell" Guid="{a0c1853b-5c40-4b15-8766-3cf1c58f985a}" /> 
  <EventID>40961</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>4</Task> 
  <Opcode>1</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-01-15T12:52:28.732178600Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4419</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{662e295f-d457-0007-449e-526657d4d601}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="98188" ThreadID="98104" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>xxxxxx</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3417511222-3094177166-1399592043-83828" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData /> 
  </Event>

 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell" Guid="{a0c1853b-5c40-4b15-8766-3cf1c58f985a}" /> 
  <EventID>53504</EventID> 
  <Version>1</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>111</Task> 
  <Opcode>10</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-01-15T12:52:28.836163000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4420</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation ActivityID="{662e295f-d457-0007-449e-526657d4d601}" /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="98188" ThreadID="49148" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>xxxxxx</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3417511222-3094177166-1399592043-83828" /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">98188</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">DefaultAppDomain</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

**Update #2**

Apologies, I missed a few things in `gpedit`. The following are set "Disabled" under computer configuration:

- Limit the maximum network bandwidth for BITS background transfers
- Prevent changing lock screen and logn image

The following are set to "Enabled" under computer configuration:

- Configure Offer Remote Assistance
- Do not allow update deferral policies to cause scans against Windows Update
- Specify intranet Microsoft update service location

The events from Event Viewer relating to 5312 and 5313 can be downbloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/dknmd8p8dn43mfn/events.evtx?dl=0

Turning on Script Execution in `gpedit` did not make any difference.

**Update #3**

Logging on with local admin user made no difference, the issue remains.

**Update #4**

Finally managed to get somewhere:

- Suspend Bitlocker protection (under Manage Bitlocker)
- Reboot in safe mode & log in with local admin
- Rename `mcshield.exe` to something like `mcshield.old` in `C:\Windows\Program Files\McAfee\Endpoint Security\Threat Prevention\AMCore`
- Reboot in normal mode
- Everything now working as usual (PowerShell and all other applications relying on execution of scripts)!!

So the issue seems to be related to the anti-virus McAfee. I have reported this to IT who will hopefully fix it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118512/discussion-on-question-by-am304-powershell-wont-load-fully-on-windows-10).

Comment: what bit-ness is the version of PoSh that is being called? does that match the bitness that your code requires?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey whether I use the 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit version of PS makes no difference.

Comment: @am304 - please add that to your Question. unfortunately, i am out of ideas ... i will go back to lurking. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: Did you try `PowerShell –noprofile` ?

Comment: @Theo, yes see extended discussion in chat. I have also just updated the question. It seems the issue is related to the anti-virus software.