# PowerShell start not complete

Tags: windows-10, powershell

PowerShell

td;dr PowerShell runs only as Admin

## symptome

if I run PowerShell.exe it runs until window is open then stops and just shows:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Lernen Sie das neue plattformübergreifende PowerShell kennen – https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

I miss: The loading of profiles ...

CTRL+c doesn't work

can be closed with CTRL+BREAK

`PowerShell -NoProfile` doesn't work

run within CMD doesn't work

I can run `powershell -version 2`

`C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe` : has the same issues

no errors in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Windows PowerShell.evtx` just:

```
Protokollname: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell
Datum:         03.02.2023 13:00:00
Ereignis-ID:   53504
Aufgabenkategorie:PowerShell Named Pipe IPC
Ebene:         Informationen
Schlüsselwörter:Keine
Benutzer:      LAPTOP-FBFN60TK\t.richter
Computer:      LAPTOP-FBFN60TK
Beschreibung:
Windows PowerShell hat einen IPC-Listeningthread für den Prozess 25024 in AppDomain DefaultAppDomain gestartet.
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell" Guid="{a0c1853b-5c40-4b15-8766-3cf1c58f985a}" />
    <EventID>53504</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>111</Task>
    <Opcode>10</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-03T12:00:00.8700204Z" />
    <EventRecordID>9372</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{e074b4ae-37a4-0006-2c1c-88e0a437d901}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="25024" ThreadID="7944" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP-FBFN60TK</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-4064394761-1642064984-2675804077-1003" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">25024</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">DefaultAppDomain</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>

Protokollname: Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational
Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell
Datum:         03.02.2023 13:00:00
Ereignis-ID:   40961
Aufgabenkategorie:Start der PowerShell-Konsole
Ebene:         Informationen
Schlüsselwörter:Keine
Benutzer:      LAPTOP-FBFN60TK\t.richter
Computer:      LAPTOP-FBFN60TK
Beschreibung:
PowerShell-Konsole wird gestartet.
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell" Guid="{a0c1853b-5c40-4b15-8766-3cf1c58f985a}" />
    <EventID>40961</EventID>
    <Version>1</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>4</Task>
    <Opcode>1</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-03T12:00:00.5136881Z" />
    <EventRecordID>9371</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{e074b4ae-37a4-0006-2c1c-88e0a437d901}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="25024" ThreadID="5448" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-PowerShell/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>LAPTOP-FBFN60TK</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-4064394761-1642064984-2675804077-1003" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

### admin

I can run an admin PowerShell with a lnk file.

I can't run admin PowerShell with Win+R PowerShell -Verb RunAs

### env

Windows 10 22H2

### ExecutionPolicy

```
S C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------

MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    Unrestricted
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

## What I did

- actual version with winget (7.3.1.0)
- windows feature powershell: disabled + enabled

## Possible reasons

?

## Solution

"Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: [What security software do you have?](https://superuser.com/questions/1617848/powershell-wont-load-fully-on-windows-10)

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Actually, check your `path` environmental variables and see if powershell and pwsh are listed in there correctly, I got my wires crossed on the previous comment. Use `where powershell.exe` and `where pwsh.exe` to see full paths as well to ensure all are interpreted, defined, and look properly configured there. Not sure if you could trick system defaults here or not, just something simple to check just in case.